# TreeView のチェックボックスのチェック方法

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

タイトルの件、asp.netのTreeViewで全てのノードにCheckBoxを表示させた場合、
子ノードをチェックした際に、該当する親ノードをチェックし、
親ノードをチェックしたら子ノードを全てチェックするやり方を
ご存知でしたら教えて頂きたいです。

JavaScriptが必要ではと考えております。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

本家S.O.にちょうど良い記事がありました。解決しています。
[asp.net treeview checkbox selection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1437617/9014308)

> クライアントサイドでは、親ノードをチェックするとき - ポストバックやajaxを使用せずにすべての子ノードをチェックするにはどうすればよいですか。

また上記を基にした日本語の記事があるので、こちらの方が良いかもしれません。
[TreeViewにおいて親子関係のチェックを付ける方法 | asp.net](https://itblogdsi.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-123.html)

> TreeViewにおいて全ての子ノードにチェックがONの場合、親ノードのチェックをONにする、または親ノードのチェックをOFFにした場合、子ノードのチェックをOFFにする方法をご紹介いたします。
>
> 似たような事例が以下のURLに載っていますが、子ノードのチェックをOFFにした場合の仕様が異なるため、ここに記載します。

「以下のURL」が本家S.O.の記事です。

そして本家S.O.の記事で、「ポストバック」と書いてあることに関連して、`AutoPostBack` プロパティがTreeViewでは効果が無いことへの対策が、上記日本語サイトの別の記事にあります。
[TreeViewでチェックボックスの変更イベントを発生させる方法（ポストバック方法） | asp.net](https://itblogdsi.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-122.html)

> asp.netにてポストバックを発生させる方法は、通常の場合サーバーコントロールに AutoPostBack="True" としますが、TreeViewでは AutoPostBackは効果が無く、Javascriptによってポストバックを発生させる必要があります。